# Set the default encoding to UTF-8 for all JSPs without using @page directives

Tags: jsp, utf-8, character-encoding

What I would like to avoid is specifying a page directive at the beginning of every JSP.

As I understand, without the following line, the default for the Content-Type for the page will be set to "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1".

`<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>`

Is there a configuration option that does the same thing without having to explicitly set the charset for every single JSP file in an application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the following to web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        <default-content-type>text/html</default-content-type>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: After fighting with the server a bit, it seems this may have done the trick.

Comment: Warning about this: I've done this in an AppEngine project, and as soon as I upgraded to Java8, the JSPs stopped working.