# How to set default character encoding in an HttpServlet, HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, html, tomcat, encoding, utf-8

In the same way that

`HttpServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

works to decode post data as UTF-8, I am wondering if there is a Tomcat configuration setting to have HttpServletRequest objects set to decode UTF-8 by default without having to explicitly have that line of code in my servlet.

Since we are able to set default encoding for the client side with a configuration setting ([Set the default encoding to UTF-8 for all JSPs without using @page directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407500/set-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-all-jsps-without-using-page-directives)) it would seem to follow that there is a way to set encoding on the server side as well.

I've read in some places that setting the encoding is a job for the client side so if I am trying to go about this the wrong way, let me know.

Comment: I don't understand, what are you trying to decode?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis For example: “UTF-8 String” sent via HTML form. Note that the quotes here are UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: So basically you want what `setCharacterEncoding` provides but without calling it?

Comment: Exactly. The idea here being configuration over code.

Comment: I believe the answer is Servlet container specific. What container are you using?

Comment: I haven't yet grasped what a servlet container actually is. I'm using Apache Tomcat if that's relevant.

Comment: Servlet is a technology, an API, that Java has developed for implementing server/client applications. Servlet applications can only be run within Servlet containers. Tomcat is one such container.

Comment: Ah, of course, I left that part out. Edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SetCharacterEncodingFilter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Set_Character_Encoding_Filter). [This wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding) is also helpful for you.

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for.